# Can't launch Visual Studio Addin example Woodgrove Expenses

Tags: visual-studio, office-js

I am getting into Excel office add-in dev and trying to get the Woodgrove example (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-WoodGrove-Expense-Trends) up and running. Unfortunately, it gives an error when I launch it.

```
Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1 in https::/localhost:App/Home/Functions.js

.... - Javascript runtime error: 'args' is undefined
```

Any ideas whether I am missing a setting?

Comment: I'd suggest that you [log an issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-WoodGrove-Expense-Trends/issues) within that GitHub repo. Additionally, it looks like that repo was created nearly 2 years ago -- **a lot** has changed with the Office.js APIs since then, so this probably isn't a great basis for learning Excel add-in development these days.

Comment: As an alternative, I'd suggest that you check out the [Excel add-ins quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/), the [Excel add-in tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial), and [Excel add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview) section of the Office Add-ins docs.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I can't really use the excel tutorial as I need something that many people can use not just Office 365 users with the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in that file. On the very first line, delete the string "args".
In the meantime, I will fix the sample.

**Update 3/2/18:** You're correct, there was a lot more corruption in that file than just that typo on the first line. I think I found it all and pushed the new version of the file to the repo. It works for me now. If you do a pull now, you should get an uncorrupted version. See if it works for you now.

Comment: thanks for updating, but unfortunately it is sill faulty. There are a number of other typos in that file (a in line 191 / 201). When I remove those as well and try to use the app it comes back with "ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working"